# "Nice" 2D ellipse in 3D space

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I would like to draw a "nice" 2D ellipse in 3D space using tikz. I'm using the tikz packages and tikz library arrows.meta

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

This is my code so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0, line cap=round, line join=round, >=Triangle]
\draw [->] (0,-1.75) -- (0,1.75); %z
\draw [->] (0.81,1.05) -- (-0.81,-1.05); %x
\draw [->] (-2.35,0) -- (2.35,0); %y
\draw (-1.15,-1.01) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {x}$};
\draw (2.40,0.15) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {y}$};
\draw (-0.05,2.20) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {z}$};
\draw[color=red, rotate around={25:(0,0)}] (0,0) ellipse (2.5cm and 1.00cm);
\draw [fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code produces the plot below
[image]

Is there any way to improve the 3D effect of the ellipse in 3D space?

Comment: Are we to presume the ellipse lies in the *x-y* plane, or is that not the case?

Comment: The ellipse is actually at an angle to all planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possibilities, depending on whether the elliptical plane is presumed to be in the *x-y* plane or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0, line cap=round, line join=round, >=Triangle]
\draw [->] (0,-1.75) -- (0,1.75); %z
\draw [->] (0.81,1.05) -- (-0.81,-1.05); %x
\draw [->] (-2.35,0) -- (2.35,0); %y
\draw (-1.15,-1.01) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {x}$};
\draw (2.40,0.15) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {y}$};
\draw (-0.05,2.20) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {z}$};
\draw[color=red, rotate around={25:(0,0)}] (0,0) ellipse (2.5cm and 1.00cm);
\draw [fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [->, red] (0,0) -- (0,0.5); %z
\draw (0.05,0.70) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {\hat n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0, line cap=round, line join=round, >=Triangle]
\draw [->] (0,-1.75) -- (0,1.75); %z
\draw [->] (0.81,1.05) -- (-0.81,-1.05); %x
\draw [->] (-2.35,0) -- (2.35,0); %y
\draw (-1.15,-1.01) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {x}$};
\draw (2.40,0.15) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {y}$};
\draw (-0.05,2.20) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {z}$};
\draw[color=red, rotate around={25:(0,0)}] (0,0) ellipse (2.5cm and 1.00cm);
\draw [fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [->, red] (0,0) -- (-.2,0.5); %z
\draw (-0.47,0.70) node[anchor=north west] {\Large $ {\hat n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `tikz-3dplot`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0, line cap=round, line join=round, >=Triangle,tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0)node[left]{$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3)node[left]{$z$};
\draw[color=red] (0,0,0) ellipse (2.5cm and 1.00cm);
\draw [fill] (0,0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And then play with the viewing angles and/or draw the ellipse in a rotated plane.

**EDIT**: Just for fun: a rotated ellipse.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0, line cap=round, line join=round, >=Triangle,tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0)node[left]{$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3)node[left]{$z$};
\draw [fill] (0,0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[color=red] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,samples=360]
({2.5*cos(\x)},{sin(\x)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]